# php Ldap connection issues

Tags: php, ldap

Please have a look at the following. I have attached the details of th DN settings and of the user account. I was able to Authenticate the account with LDP.exe with the correct details.

I get the error of when running this script

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in /var/www/html/portal/ldap.php on line 8
```

Below is the php script that i'm trying to get working.

```
<?php

$ldapconn = ldap_connect("server_url") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding anonymously
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn,'uid=Lyall,cn=Domain Admins,cn=Users,dc=svo,dc=local','Password');

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind anonymous failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

Here is a screenshot of the DN settings

[image: ldap dn]

Here is a screenshot of a user that im testing with

[image: ldap user]

I have used LDP.exe and was able to Authenticate the details.

```
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity, NEGOTIATE (1158)); // v.3
    {NtAuthIdentity: User='lyall'; Pwd=<unavailable>; domain = 'cn=Domain Admins,cn=Users,dc=svo,dc=local'}
Authenticated as: 'SVO\Lyall'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such attribute as `uid` in Active Directory. The distinguished name of your account most likely starts with `CN=`. If you have access to Powershell's Active Directory module (usually installed on a domain controller or a computer designated to manage the domain) you can inspect your full distinguished name by running the following:

```
Get-ADUser YOUR_LOGINID_HERE -Properties DistinguishedName
```

*(I hope I got it right, it's been a while since I used PS)*

Anyway, A DN is not the only attribute you can use to authenticate/bind to Active Directory - you can use a multitude of other, more easily rememberable options:

- `samAccountName`: *SVO\Lyall*
- `userPrincipalName`: *Lyall@svo.local* (sometimes it's the same as email address, depends on how you name your user accounts)
- `DisplayName`

See [Simple Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx) on MSDN for a thorough description on which attributes are available.

**Warning** - self-propaganda follows:
*I have written some libraries that make it easier to work with ldap so if you are interested, take a look at [Ldap-Core](https://github.com/Dreamscapes/Ldap-Core).*

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the DN of Lyall is `uid=Lyall,cn=Domain Admins,cn=Users,dc=svo,dc=local`? For me it looks like Lyall is just a member of the group `cn=Domain Admins,cn=Users,dc=svo,dc=local`. That does not necessary mean Lyells DN is `uid=Lyall,cn=Domain Admins,cn=Users,dc=svo,dc=local`. It could also be `uid=Lyall,cn=Users,dc=svo,dc=local` or something else. Perhaps that might help you solve the issue.